# how to prevent launch of installed application in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install the Skype on my machine. Even though I used "/NOLAUNCH" argument after the install it is launching the skype application. how can I prevent the launch of the application?  even install command is also taking a lot of time after install it is taking lot of time to come out of that.

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "$Save_Dir\Skype_Install.exe" -ArgumentList " /qn /VERYSILENT /SP- /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOLAUNCH" -Wait -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
```

how can I solve these 2 issues.

Comment: I think you should not use the `-PassThru` switch

Comment: @Theo,Without -PassThru also skype is launching,

Comment: @surendra did you run powershell as administrator?

Comment: @rufer7 Yes...i am using powershell as administartor..

Comment: I'm not too sure about the ` /qn ` you start your Argumentlist with.. Try with `-ArgumentList "/VERYSILENT /SP- /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOLAUNCH"`

Answer (score 1):

As commented, I think the `/qn` argument is not valid for the Skype-Install.exe.

`/qn` is a standard parameter for .msi files used by the [Msiexec.exe](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html). It is not used as commandline switch for the [Skype_Install.exe](http://www.get-itsolutions.com/skype-silent-install-msi-and-disable-updates/#124) application.

Try this:

```
try {
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath "$Save_Dir\Skype_Install.exe" -ArgumentList "/VERYSILENT /SP- /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOLAUNCH" -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
```

I have added the `-WindowStyle Hidden` parameter to simulate the `/qn`

Hope this helps